# Different timeout values in print composer and regular map view in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, export, print-composer

I'm experiencing some issues in the print composer when exporting maps including WMS-layers.

One of the WMS-layers takes a lot of time to load, and I've increased the timeout for network requests in the Network tab (QGIS main window: Settings->Options->Network) to get the WMS-layer to load.

This works when viewing the layers/maps in the print composer as well. If I open the settings window in print composer (Settings->Layout options->Network) I see the same timeout value I entered in the main QGIS window. This makes sense as they most likely point to the same settings.

However, when I'm exporting the map to a PDF from the print composer, the WMS-layer that takes a lot of time to load is not included in the export. I have some vector layers on top of it, and they're included in the export, but not the WMS-layer itself. The other WMS-layers that's in the map view in the print composer are included as normal.

My theory is that the print composer uses a different timeout value when exporting to PDF. Is this true? If yes, where can I increase this value to ensure that the WMS-layer loads properly?

Edit:
To clarify, the problem is that the WMS layer loads properly in QGIS and in the print composer just fine. The issue I'm having is that the WMS layer does not load when I'm *exporting* the map. The WMS-layer is not included in the exported PDF. (but loads just fine in the print composer)

Comment: It's possible that the WMS server has a time out that you are exceeding, Try switching to a tiled layer using WMTS

Comment: The problem is that the WMS layer loads properly in QGIS and in the print composer just fine. The issue I'm having is that the WMS layer does not load when I'm _exporting_ the map. The WMS-layer is not included in the exported PDF. (but loads just fine in the print composer)

Comment: QGis requests the printed map (when printing) at a higher DPI which leads to a bigger map.

Comment: Yes, but that's not really an issue. I'm exporting atlases with a fixed map size/scale, so on some of the pages the WMS-layer is included, and on some they're not included. That makes me think that the pages that's not included is because the WMS-server takes to long to respond, and QGIS then skips to the next atlas page instead of waiting on the server. (and that's why I would like to know if there's a way to increase the timeout value when _exporting_ maps)

Comment: but I think you will find that it is the WMS server itself timing out as you are exporting at roughly 3 times the resolution of the screen display.